# Getting permission denied error

Tags: 12.04, permissions, ssh, sudo, su

I have written one bash script and it is run on the background, inside this script I have use the following  command:

```
sshpass -p prakash123 ssh -t -p $1 prakash@localhost './update_script.sh > /update.out 2> /update.err < /dev/null | echo $! > /update.pid &'
```

It is working fine. But I want to change the location of `/update.out` ,`/update.err` and `/update.pid`  So modified command for that:

```
sshpass -p prakash123 ssh -t -p $1 prakash@localhost './update_script.sh > /pra/log/update.out 2> /pra/log/update.err < /dev/null | echo $! > /pra/log/update.pid &'
```

Now I am getting the permission denied error.

Because I changed the path of output files. I am not sure but I think I have to give the super user permission like `su` or `sudo` before the `sshpass`

So how can I change the path of `/update.out` , `/update.err` and `/update.pid` this file from the above command.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the first command, you are writing the output to a location that you have write access to, so everything is fine there.

Now the `/pra` directory does not exist by default, so I assume you have created it using root access.
So to write to it, you have to use root access as well. Just add `sudo` to the command as,

```
sudo sshpass -p prakash123 ssh -t -p $1 prakash@localhost './update_script.sh > /pra/log/update.out 2> /pra/log/update.err < /dev/null | echo $! > /pra/log/update.pid &'
```

But rather than doing this ,I would suggest you write to a directory in `$HOME` dir and give it `rwx------` permission(i.e read/write/execute for you and no permissions to others).Thus you won't have to use `sudo.`

Comment: /pra/log/ directory is exist by default. I think sudo is best option for me because I am not able to change the directory permission /pra/log because other user also have access of this directory.                                                                                                                        I tried your command but ./update_script.sh file not executed. In your above command what is "entersshpass" you mean this is superuser pass or anything else.

Comment: @prakash there are some unwanted guests in the command. Just add sudo before your command. I will edit the answer later when using my computer.

Comment: sure, I have added sudo before my command but it is not working for me. I am not getting  /update.out , /update.err and /update.pid files inside the /pra/log directory.

Comment: @PrakashVHolkar post the error.

Comment: I am getting following error:    Host key verification failed.